# Aligning a button (center right)

Tags: html, css

I am building a coming soon website, it's currently hosted [here](http://zakshaky.github.io/) but I am unable to align the button correctly. I would like it to be aligned to the right of the text field. How can I do this?

My current code is:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm6-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
   <form action="//joghr.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992&amp;id=2e27b33636" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" name = "EMAIL" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: -10000000px;top: -43px;float: top;overflow: auto;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992_2e27b33636" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Notify Me</button>
     </form
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this style:

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll > .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
}
#mc_embed_signup_scroll > button {
    float: right;
}
```

or try this:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group" style="width: auto;">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992_2e27b33636" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Notify Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the `button` tag inside of the `form-group` div.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm6-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
   <form action="//joghr.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992&amp;id=2e27b33636" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                            <input type="email" name = "EMAIL" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
                            <div style="position: absolute; left: -10000000px;top: -43px;float: top;overflow: auto;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992_2e27b33636" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill">Notify Me</button>
                      </div>

     </form
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this to button:

```
position: absolute;
right: aaapx;
```

in right add the number that you want to fix in that position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm6-6 col-sm-offset-3 ">
   <form action="//joghr.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992&amp;id=2e27b33636" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
           <div class="form-group" style="width:auto; float:left;">
             <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
               <input type="email" name = "EMAIL" class="form-control transparent" placeholder="Your email here...">
               <div style="position: absolute; left: -10000000px;top: -43px;float: top;overflow: auto;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_0afaeb9185d575ddab99c7992_2e27b33636" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-fill" style="float:left">Notify Me</button>
     </form
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Well, I think that you will do that, but those 'style' attributes may be created properly in your css stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert your button inside the another div with form-group class and add extra 'text-right' class to make it centre-right aligned... Hope this is what you want... Have a look at the code below...

```
        <div class="form-group  text-right">
                  <button type="submit"
```

class="btn btn-danger btn-
fill">Notify Me

```
     </div>
```